# Match everything up to a specific character whether it exists or not

Tags: regex

How do I match everything on the line but stop when I find a semicolon? If I never find one I should continue matching even if one doesn't exist.

Here is some sample input:

```
captureme; dontcaptureme
captureme andme andme
captureme andme andme; butnotme
```

I've tried a lazy quantifier `(\w*?);` but it won't work if I make the semicolon optional. See [my current regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/fU5nG8/1) here.

Comment: Just it: `(^[^;\n]+)`

Comment: Do you want to capture multi-lines until a semi-colon is found? i.e., in your example, should the second line be its own match or should it be keep matching into line 3 until the semi-colon is found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
^[^;\n]*
```

With multiline modifier.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI1vN0/3)

The `^` in a multiline mode will match at the beginning of a line, and the negated character class `[^;\n]` will match any character but a semi-colon or a newline symbol. `*` will make the regex engine match those characters 0 or more times. Thus, if you do not want to match emoty lines, use the `+` quantifier instead.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well:

```
^(.*?)(?:;|$)
```

[Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/fU5nG8/3)